# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I don't know why I am getting an error.

I am using a different java class to connect to database. This is my code:

```java
public class DBConnection {
    static Connection connect;

    public static void setConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ubli", "admin", "admin123");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR! Can't Connect to server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return connect;
    }
```

this is the getSpecificField code:

```
   public String getSpecificField(String query)
       {
           String record=null;
           try
           {
               rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
               if(rs.first())
               {
                   metadata=rs.getMetaData();
                   
                   for(int col=0; col<metadata.getColumnCount(); col++)
                   {
                           
                       record=rs.getString(col);
                   }
               }

           }catch(Exception e)
           {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR");
           }
           return record;
       }
```

I have this error even though I'm sure that my table exists:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'ubli.ubli' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1200)
    at ub.li.QueryProcessor.getSpecificField(QueryProcessor.java:106)
    at ub.li.Home.<init>(Home.java:32)
    at ub.li.UBLI.main(UBLI.java:19)
```

Please help me with my project.

Comment: I assume that `QueryProcessor` is a [Java] class that you wrote. According to the stack trace you posted, method `getSpecificField`, in that class, is throwing `SQLSyntaxErrorException`. Perhaps you should [edit] your question and post the code of that method?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Hello, It looks like an issue with a schema in use. The error means: a table 'ubli' in the schema 'ubli' doesn't exist. I guess you have a table 'ubli' defined in the database but not in the schema 'ubli'. In this case try to access the table without a schema.

Comment: check if your table by  table name : `schemaName`.`tableName` is Existing ?

Comment: Given the error message `Table 'ubli.ubli' doesn't exist` I'm going to hazard a guess that the table 'ubli.ubli' doesn't exist.